# convergence of a sum with zeroes of zeta function

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Can it be proved that the sum of this series is smaller than $x$?
$$
\sum_{\zeta(a+ib)=0}u_{a,b}(x)\lt x,
$$
for all $x$, with
$$
u_{a,b}(x)=\frac{2ax^a\sqrt{x^{2a}+(x-1)^{2a}-2x^a(x-1)^a\cos(\theta-\gamma)}\cos\Big(\theta-\tan^{-1}v\Big)}{a^2+b^2}
$$ 
and
$$
\theta=2b\ln(x),\quad \gamma=2b\ln(x-1),\quad v=\frac{-x^a\sin\theta-(x-1)^a\sin\gamma}{x^a\cos\theta-(x-1)^a\cos\gamma}
$$
So $a<1$ and the smallest known $b$ is $\approx 14$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited to make the formula a bit easier to read, make sure I didn't ruin anything. What do you mean by "converges before $x$"? And where did this problem come from? This is a pretty nasty formula...

Comment: This means that the value of this sum is leser than x.It only looks nasty . Value of cos x ranges from 1 to -1 . The maximum value of root can be $x^a+(x-1)^a$ and minimum $x^a-(x-1)^a$ .Thanks for editing.

Comment: Splitted some identities to make them less wide than the page.

Comment: (1.) Where does this come from? (2.) Can you prove the same result but without the cosine factor?